# Python TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable i'm trying to iterate over a len(list) but it's giving me this error

Tags: list

```
a = ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb'] 
for i in range(len(a)):
    print(i)
```

its giving me this error aftr i run the above code

#TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

The code above you run works fine. There is no error in it.

If you want to iterate with a running index, you can do so by using **enumerate**:

```
your_list = ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb'] 
for index, element in enumerate(your_list):
    print(index, element)
```

yields:

```
0 Mary
1 had
2 a
3 little
4 lamb
```

Iterating without an index works without enumerate:

```
  your_list = ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb'] 
    for element in your_list:
        print(element)
```

yields:

```
Mary
had
a
little
lamb
```

Comment: Thank you David for your answer, I was trying to take the length of the list as a parameter inside the parenthesis ...i.e .... for i in range(len(a)): and it's giving me an error... also is there is a whole lot of problem in using range within the for loop in my notebook. I mean even running (for i in range(10), print(i), gives me the same error i.e TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable....what might be the problem sir?

Comment: Post a screenshot, so i can see